# Manual Form Positioning

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

How can I position a subform based on the position of a control in the parent form. I realize I can set the start up position of the subform to manual and assign values to the location property manually.
But what i want to do is position the subform just above a control on the main form.
All this has to be done during runtime ofcourse.
Any help appreciated.

I am using Csharp and working on a Winform application on visual studio 2008, .net 3.5 sp1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code that does it:

```
var loc = this.PointToScreen(this.txtLocator.Location);
```

The loc variable will contain the screen coordinates of the control, and you can set your child form's location to this.

**EDIT:** *this*, by the way, is the parent form in the above code